# GSSContext возвращает null'овый SrcName

Tags: java, spring-security, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos

Я пытаюсь прикрутить к своему Java web приложению SSO на основе доменной авторизации. Как я понял, наиболее легче это сделать при помощи Kerberos. И я вроде поправил все стандартные проблемы с ним(например присылается токен NTLM,  а не керберос). Но столкнулся с проблемой, которой никак не могу найти решение. После всех проверок токена, в GSSContext не появляется данных и он остаётся в статусе `not established`.

Попытка следовать [этому мануалу](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/single-signon.html) и отправлять данные обратно в браузер в ожидании нового токена ничего не дала. Попробовал настроить спринг секурити для кербероса, он падает абсолютно с такой же проблемой:

https://spring.io/blog/2009/09/28/spring-security-kerberos-spnego-extension

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>     org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:136)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:125)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)

```
private static class KerberosValidateAction implements PrivilegedExceptionAction<String> {
    byte[] kerberosTicket;

    public KerberosValidateAction(byte[] kerberosTicket) {
        this.kerberosTicket = kerberosTicket;
    }

    @Override
    public String run() throws Exception {
        GSSContext context = GSSManager.getInstance().createContext((GSSCredential) null);
        context.acceptSecContext(kerberosTicket, 0, kerberosTicket.length);
        String user = context.getSrcName().toString(); // ERROR!
        context.dispose();
        return user;
    }

}
```

**Update:**

Попробовал изменить версию Java, как предложено в тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747565/domain-authentication-with-kerberos-fails. Ничего не поменялось.

**Update 2:**

Для начала. Не используйте Java 1.8 b40 и b45, оба этих билда сломаны. И не пытайтесь тестировать на локальном компе, это тоже не работает(кривой тикет присылается, хз почему)

После того, как я поменял версию java на b65, я стал получить ошибку шифрования(Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - AES256 ...). Это фиксится скачиванием и установкой Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) для Java 1.8, [отсюда](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) и пересозданием keytab файла с параметром `/crypto AES256-SHA1`. После всех манипуляций я стал получать ошибку:

> GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level:
>   Checksum failed) at
>   sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source) at
>   GssServer$GssServerAction.run(GssServer.java:159) 
>   ... 4 more 
>   Caused by: KrbException: Checksum failed at
>   sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType.decrypt(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmacEType.decrypt(Unknown
>   Source) at sun.security.krb5.EncryptedData.decrypt(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.authenticate(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.security.jgss.krb5.InitSecContextToken.(Unknown Source)
>   ... 8 more 
>   Caused by: java.security.GeneralSecurityException: Checksum
>   failed at
>   sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.ArcFourCrypto.decrypt(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.ArcFourHmac.decrypt(Unknown Source)
>   ... 14 more

Я пытался использовать [этот туториал](https://dmdaa.wordpress.com/2010/03/13/kerberos-setup-and-jaas-configuration-for-running-sun-jgss-tutorial-against-ad/) для пересоздания keytab, но всё безрезультатно. Так же я пробовал различные другие способы пересоздания файла, ничего не помогает.

Comment: тебе обязательно использовать kerberos или главное чтобы было SSO (к примеру jasig)?

Comment: @Темкатоже мне главное, чтобы было через доменный аккаунт(виндовый).

Comment: Тут помочь не могу. Такого рода аутентификацию не настраивал.